# Can't Find features.h Compiling mod_pagespeed on Raspberry Pi (armv6l)

Tags: linux, gcc, nginx, raspberry-pi, pagespeed

I am trying to [build the PSOL (PageSpeed Optimization Libraries) from source](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/wiki/Building-PSOL-From-Source) on a Raspberry Pi running [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) to use the [ngx_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) module with [nginx](http://nginx.org/). I have run into a compilation error that I can't seem to fix. I encounter the error whilst trying to build mod_pagespeed with

```
make AR.host="$PWD/build/wrappers/ar.sh" \
     AR.target="$PWD/build/wrappers/ar.sh" \
     BUILDTYPE=Release \
     mod_pagespeed_test pagespeed_automatic_test
```

The error is

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/arm-linux-gnueabihf/./bits/c++config.h:393:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.h:7,
                 from out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb/net/instaweb/rewriter/image_types.pb.cc:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/arm-linux-gnueabihf/./bits/os_defines.h:40:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
```

features.h is located in /usr/include which can be seen from

```
user@hostname ~ $ ls -la /usr/include | grep features.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  13040 Mar 20 22:56 features.h
```

Running `cpp -v` lists the include search folders as

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The include is in os_defines.h on line 40 as `#include <features.h>`.

I have build-essential-11.5+b1, gcc-4:4.6.3-8, cpp-4:4.6.3-8, g++-4:4.6.3-8, libc6-2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u1, libc6-dev-2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u1 all installed. Googling seems too suggest installing/re-installing build-essential and libc6-dev should fix the problem but it has had no effect. There are also suggestions that installing gcc-multilib might help but apt-get has no installation candidate for it. Would it be possible for me to install [gcc-4.6-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gcc-4.6-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf) manually, and would this solve my issues?

I have no idea of what I can try next to fix this and would be very great full for any help. If there's anything else you need me to add please let me know.

**UPDATE (2014-08-06)**

I have tried compiling mod_pagespeed on my Raspberry Pi this time running [Arch Linux Arm](http://archlinuxarm.org/) with gcc-4.8.2-7 and I have hit the exact same error. It appears to me as if this is an error with gcc for armv6l devices.

I have also tried editing the include directive in os_defines.h to include the full path to features.h but this caused a Segmentation Fault error.